# Saving Core Data using AlertView and immediately in Cell

Tags: ios, core-data

When I push a cell, an AlertView with Prompt is popping up. My problem: I want to show the entered text from the prompt in to the selected cell. (and in the meantime save the text to Core Data). Can anyone push me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the save in a background thread, if you want it to happen at the same time as the alert is showing.

The easiest approach is using nested contexts, and just saving from the main context.

Wherever you are creating your managed object context, replace the alloc/init part with...

```
NSManagedObjectContext *parentMoc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
parentMoc.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator;
self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
self.managedObjectContext.parentContext = parenetMoc;
```

Now, you have the same MOC you were using before, except it is a main queue MOC, with a parent context running in a background queue.

You will have to use a method to save both contexts though.  The second save, on the parent, happens in a background thread, so you do not have to wait.

```
- (void)saveData {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext;
    if ([moc save:&error]) {
        moc = moc.parentContext;
        [moc performBlock:^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![moc save:&error]) {
                // Handle the actual save error
            }
        }];
    } else {
        // Handle the error of saving up into the parent context...
    }
}
```

Now, instead of calling [managedObjectContext save:&error] directly, replace it with a message of saveData, and the method will return almost immediately, and the actual save will happen in a background thread.

None of your other code in your app (except for the save calls) should have to change at all.

In your case, right before you throw up the alert, call save, and the save will happen while the alert is being displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer but are you sure that this is the way to save the text from the prompt in the alertview ? Cause your talking about: " the save will happen while the alert is being displayed." actually the save need to happen when i click 'save' in the alertview ..

Comment: From your question, I took that you wanted to save your core data context in the background while you were displaying the alert.  If you  are looking for something different, then maybe try enhancing your question, because now I have no idea what you are after.

Comment: There is a cell, I push that cell, an alertview pops up, I enter text in this alertview, this entered text I want to be showed in the selected cell and in the meantime save in core data. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Ummm... what's wrong with using the delegate and textFieldAtIndex: ?